# How to add view to frame

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app I want to create a `Frame` programmatically and add a view to it as a child:

```
var child = new Label()
var frame = new Frame();
// How do I add child to frame?
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
var child = new Label();
var frame = new Frame
{
    Content = child
};
```

Official documentation can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/).